# Is it possible to use static UITableViewCell and add sections on them?

Tags: ios5, uitableview, ios6

Is it possible to use static UITableViewCell and add sections on them?

[image]

It would be great if I could separate these cells into Twitter, Facebook and Other for example.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Oh man, that's embarrassing. I've just seen it on the IB below "Content"